# Cannot load context properties in a Spring Boot test

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, spring-boot, junit

I try to write a test for a method which uses the attributes defined in the `application.properties`, but it seems that the Spring context cannot be loaded in the test.

**MyProperties.java**

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "test")
public class MyProperties {

    private String name;
    private String gender;
    private String age;

    public String getInformation(){
        return name + gender + age;
    }
}
```

**application.properties**

```
test.name=JASON
test.gender=MALE
test.age=23
```

**Test.java**

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class Test {

    @Autowired
    private MyProperties myProperties;

    @Test
    public void getInformation(){
        assertEquals("JASONMALE23", myProperties.getInformation());
    }
}
```

The result of this test is **nullnullnull**, can anyone tell me how to solve this problem?

Comment: where have you put your `application.properties`? Make a separate `application.proprties` for test configs and put it under `src/test/resources` and spring boot will auto-load them

Comment: sorry, I can't test it but maybe `classpath:/application.properties`?=))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@ConfigurationProperties` requires both getters and setters for the fields representing a property. You have not declared them in your code so Spring Boot thinks there are no properties to inject.

Add the missing methods:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "test")
public class MyProperties {

  private String name;
  private String gender;
  private String age;

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  public String getGender() {
    return gender;
  }

  public void setGender(String gender) {
    this.gender = gender;
  }

  public String getAge() {
    return age;
  }

  public void setAge(String age) {
    this.age = age;
  }

  public String getInformation(){
    return name + gender + age;
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, Karol, your solution is very helpful for me. Regarding the variable marked with @Value(${test}), it can inject the properties without the get and set method, why are they different?

Comment: `@Value` is something completely different, it's used to evaluate SpEL expressions. `@ConfigurationProperties` is just a convenient binding for properties into Java class. Two different parts of the framework with different rules.